# Error: "The inf file you selected does not support this method of installation"

Tags: windows-7, drivers, inf

I'm asking this here because a Google search for this error string turns up poor results, so hopefully some people will post better answers here and Google will index it!

While trying to install this RNDIS driver for my Linux smartphone:  http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/NeoRndis.inf

I get the error "The inf file you selected does not support this method of installation".  I get the error whether I right-click on it and click "install", or whether I go to device manager, update driver, and browse to the folder.  When I try to install it from the commandline, I get only a noninformative "installation failed" message.

The driver previously worked in Windows XP 32 bit but is not working for me in Windows 7 64 bit.

Can anyone give me more information on exactly what causes this error?  Perhaps if I knew more about it I could hack the inf file so that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Chris is right.  I don't have an OpenMoko phone to test with, but a comment on [this blog post](http://sam.curren.ws/index.cfm/2008/7/14/Using-the-Neo-FreeRunner-with-Windows-XPVista) leads to [this Vista x64 INF](http://openmoko.kamillo.pl/neo_vista_x64.inf).  The same INF is discussed on the [OpenMoko wiki's Neo1973_and_Windows page](http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/Neo1973_and_Windows):

> If you have Windows Vista x64 try this one: http://openmoko.kamillo.pl/neo_vista_x64.inf (this also works with Windows 7 x64 RC).

I don't know if it'll work on Win-7, or if it's even compatible with your device.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

32 bit drivers do not work in 64 bit operating systems