# What causes "The INF file you selected does not support this method of installation." error?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, inf

This question is related to [this](https://superuser.com/q/181716/36601) one. Also, I think it's not duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/q/94439/36601) question, since I'm not asking about specific device but a more general case.

Where can I find information about driver .inf files and how windows checks if they are usable? I know that many people do modify .inf files so there must be some information on the Internet.

Basically I have a bad .inf file and would like to see what's wrong with it and how to fix it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INF files format reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764958(v=VS.85).aspx

It would help to read the Creating Setup Applications (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376920(v=VS.85).aspx) page to learn the sequence followed, so you can step through the INF manually.  I suppose a programmer could attach a debugger to setup and figure out what its failing on.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no debugger for INF files. Attaching a debugger to setup.exe would not be much useful unless you had setup's source code and private symbols.

Answer (score 10):

In order for the "Right Click/Install" method to work, there must be a `[DefaultInstall]` section in the INF file and, potentially some other "Default" sections:

```
[DefaultInstall.Service] 
[DefaultUninstall]
[DefaultUninstall.Service]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547465(v=vs.85).aspx

If there is no `[DefaultInstall]` section, you get the message “The INF file you selected does not support this method of installation.”

Answer (score 3):

You might try to select the inf file from Device Manager:

Right-click the device, select Update Driver Software, then Let me pick, click Have disk, Browse to the inf file and install.

If this doesn't work, I don't believe you can fix the inf file. The product you have probably doesn't match your operating system (it might be 32-bit when your Windows 7 is 64-bit).

You can also give more information, such as posting the inf file (actually the entire product, if possible).

Comment: The .inf is correct because it did work on vista (but device manager method does not work for me on seven). I have 64bit seven and 64bit driver. I was asking here for general causes. [Here](http://superuser.com/q/181716/36601) is my question about my specific problems with my card reader.

Comment: You could also try to right-click the inf file and choose Install. Some inf files are funny this way, and will only work in one way, generating otherwise the above message.